# Maximizing Net Profit with Probabilities

Tags: probability

Every week a grocer has $5$ to $8$ customers who wish to buy a pumpkin, considering that the pumpkins haven't been sold. The random variable $X$ has the following function of mass probability:

$$P_x(x) = \frac{9-x}{10},~ x=5,6,7,8.$$

At the start of the week the grocer buys pumpkins for $2$ euros each, while during the week he sells them for $4$ euros. At the end of the week the grocer throws away any unsold pumpkin. If the grocer wishes to maximize his net profit, how many pumpkins will he have to buy?

Comment: Please edit this post to include what you've tried yourself